# string[] via Ajax and ASP.Net (MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, arrays

my problem is following. 
I try to parse some data via ajax, passing the data to my controller:

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ParseOrganizaitonPath",
            data: {
                organizationPath: $('#organizationPath').val()
            },
            success:
                    function (data) {
                         //data is from type string with value "System.string[]" 
                         //but should be from type System.string[] 
                        });
                    }
        });
```

**Controller**

```
public string[] ParseOrganizaitonPath(string organizationPath)
{
    List<string> organizations = organizationPath.Split('/').ToList();

    return organizations.ToArray();
}
```

I am reaching the controller method and in it everything is fine, but the data that is comming back (ajax part, success method) is just a string ("System.string[]", data[0] S, data[1]y data[2]s...) but not the data I want. (For example if i pass the input "test/one" I want to have as result *data[0] test, data[1] one*)

Hope you understand what my Problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to tried to use the JavaScriptSerializer? Have a look at this example:

```
public string ParseOrganizaitonPath(string organizationPath)
{
    List<string> organizations = organizationPath.Split('/').ToList();
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
             new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    return oSerializer.Serialize(organizations);
}
```

To deserialize the JSON string with JavaScript you can use the parse function:

```
var array = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: As this is a array converted into a string this is not what im looking for. Sorry.

Comment: Have a look at my edit which shows how to deserialize the string into an array.

Comment: Pretty cool, this is working fine, but isn't there another way to do it without serializing the return value?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way where you don't have to serialize it (on c# site) and parse it (on javascript site)

Just use the JSON Method that is inherited from the `Controller` and return an `JsonResult`:

```
public JsonResult ParseOrganizaitonPath(string organizationPath)
{
    List<string> organizations = organizationPath.Split('/').ToList();

    return JSON(organizations);
}
```

On the client site (javascript) you have to use JSON.stringfy(dataObject) for data that you want to send to your controller-method.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "ParseOrganizaitonPath",
            data: JSON.stringify(myDataObject),
            success:
                    function (data) {
                         //use your data
                        });
                    }
        });
```

That's how it worked for me.

Good luck!

Julian